# Scala mixing dependencies with same package name

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, slf4j

**The problem:**

I have 2 dependencies in Scala sbt project - `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` (direct, but used in other direct dependencies as well) and `org.fusesource.hawtjni:hawtjni-generator` (transitive). Both of them have the class `org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter`. The issues arises when a third dependency tries to call `MessageFormatter.someFunction(x)`, which should be called from `slf4j-api`, but instead it is called from `hawtjni-generator`.

**What I have tried:**

- Cleaning the IDE (Intellij) files, as I supposed it could be the IDE not recognising them properly. Didn't work...
- Adding exclusion rule for `hawtjni-generator` to all other dependencies, except the one that used it. Didn't work...

Edit:
A simplified dependency tree of the project looks like that:

```
[info]   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
[info]   +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
[info]   | 
[info]   +-com.ltonetwork:leveldbjni.leveldbjni-osx:99-master-SNAPSHOT
[info]   | +-org.fusesource.hawtjni:hawtjni-maven-plugin:1.18
[info]   |   +-org.fusesource.hawtjni:hawtjni-generator:1.18
```

The problem is with `logback-classic` (that's the third dependency) which wrongly calls `hawtjni-generator`, instead of `slf4j-api`.

Comment: You probably need to shade the slf4j dependency of hawtjni.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the reply, I have tried:
```ShadeRule.rename("org.slf4j.**" -> "shadedslf4j.@1").inLibrary("org.fusesource.hawtjni" % "hawtjni-generator" % "1.18").inProject```
but it did not help. I believe shading is in the case hawtjni had slf4j as dependency on its own, but the case here is hawtjni's own package is named as org.slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an alias for one of your imports?

```
import org.fusesource.hawtjni:hawtjni-generator
import org.slf4j.helpers.{MessageFormatter => MessageFormatterSlf4j}

MessageFormatterSlf4j.someFunctions(x) 
MessageFormatter.someFunctions(x) // from fusesource
```

[Scala import alias](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-rename-class-import-importing-syntax-examples/)

Comment: Hmmm, the thing is that this one should be done in the third dependency that I have (`logback-classic`), if I understand correctly. Ideally I was looking for solution that wouldn't require forking it only to change the imports.